Programatically stream using USBPcap (Windows USB)
I am trying to capture USB traffic in realtime on Windows. I installed USBPcap and was able to invoke USBPcapCMD.exe to save traffic to a file, as well as to output garbled output on the command line directly.
To output to a file:
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap2 -A -o file.out

To output to a command line:
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap2 -A -o - 

The latter is how the data is piped to Wireshark. However when I wrote a simple program that gets input from stdin prints only zeros:
constexpr int N=16;
unsigned char buffer[N];

while(1)
  {
  int len=fread(buffer, 1, N, stdin);
  printf("%d\n",len);
  }

I want to access the USB traffic in realtime and process myself. I am not too familiar with Windows programming, so I am not sure why I am not getting the data into my program even though it's appearing on the command line.

Not sure what you mean by effective, but efficiency is not a big goal here. Traffic is fairly small. A library like that sounds nice but unfortunately seems like it's for Ethernet only and I need usb.
